# Wordpress install permission denied, ubuntu

Tags: linux, wordpress, shell, ubuntu

i have been trying to download wordpress to ubuntu to a specific directory

```
/usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www
```

but instead getting an error permission denied

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
--2018-05-12 03:26:20--  http://wordpress.org/latest.zip
Resolving wordpress.org (wordpress.org)... 198.143.164.252
Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|198.143.164.252|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://wordpress.org/latest.zip [following]
--2018-05-12 03:26:40--  https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|198.143.164.252|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9333392 (8.9M) [application/zip]
latest.zip: Permission denied

Cannot write to ‘latest.zip’ (Permission denied).
```

how do i get permission to write to the specific folder?

```
mkdir -P /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -O /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www
tar xfp /usr/share/nginx/wp_install www latest.tar.gz
```

output:

```
/usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www: Is a directory
tar: /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar: At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

instead of -o, used -p and it did download the file, but getting file permission issues.

```
mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -p /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www latest.tar.gz
tar xfp /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www latest.tar.gz
```

output:

```
http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
Resolving wordpress.org (wordpress.org)... 198.143.164.252
Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|198.143.164.252|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz [following]
--2018-05-12 06:03:03--  https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
Connecting to wordpress.org (wordpress.org)|198.143.164.252|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 8565154 (8.2M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz’

wordpress.org/lates 100%[===================>]   8.17M   490KB/s    in 14s     

2018-05-12 06:03:18 (580 KB/s) - ‘wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz’ saved [8565154/8565154]

/usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www/latest.tar.gz: Scheme missing.
FINISHED --2018-05-12 06:03:18--
Total wall clock time: 19s
Downloaded: 1 files, 8.2M in 14s (580 KB/s)
tar: /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar: At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: Download to different directory and then move with `sudo`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing wget -o, you need to specific the file you'll write.

Where you have:

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -O /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www
```

You should have

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -O /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www/latest.tar.gz
```

Comment: yes it worked, now its giving Read-only file system error

Comment: Now seems you have an error on the last line, it should be ( tar xfp /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www/latest.tar.gz ) , please note the / after www and before latest.tar.gz

Comment: tar: /usr/share/nginx/wp_install/www/latest.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Comment: Does it have to do anything with file permissions ? Cause i saw the permissions now, the directory is in read only mode. No write no execute.